# DropDownList getSelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, controller, selectedvalue

I am currently working on a MVC Project and I made following static DropDownBox in a View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Art", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{Text="Orginal Vertrag",Value="Orginal"},
    new SelectListItem{Text="Anlage",Value="Anlage"},
    new SelectListItem{Text="Kündigung",Value="Kündigung"},
    new SelectListItem{Text="Sonstiger",Value="Sonstiges"}
}, "Dokumentenart auswählen")
```

I want to get the `SelectedValue` in a Controller Class. But if I try `Art.getSelectedValue()` it underlines the code line. So my Question is how do I get that `SelectedValue()`. So could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you POST a form, you could try to get the selected value like below:

```
var selectedArt = Request.Form["Art"];
```

Otherwise if you make a GET request, you should look in the query string parameters.

Comment: thanks that was exactly what i needed. Can i do this request with any cshtml objects like textfields, labels and so on as well?